# How to map objects data inside object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I'm calling data from JSON data as:
[image]

In short JSON data is as:

```
const listData =  [
{
"_id":"abscdf456",
"bucket": {code: "videos"}
"contents": [
{}, {}, {}, {}
]
},
{
"_id":"absusi789",
"bucket": {code: "videos"}
"contents": [
{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}
]
},
{
"_id":"abssth7890",
"bucket": {code: "photos"}
"contents": [
{}, {}, {}, {},{}, {},{}, {}, {}
]
},
{
"_id":"yuiaf456",
"bucket": {code: "videos"}
"contents": [
{}, {}, {}
]
}
]
```

I have tried in the following way

```
listData.map((data) => (
<div>
{
data.bucket.code == "videos" ? 
({/* Map only videos contents object */}) : ({/* Map only photos contents object */})
}
</div>
))
```

Another trial I did is `const videoData = listData.filter(data => data.bucket.code === "videos")`  but, no use as It got repeated many times

So basically My intention is to map the 'contents object' of each bucket non-repeated. What could be the best possible solution?

Comment: What does this mean? "Map only videos contents object"

Comment: i think you want to say filter not map

Comment: please describe your problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: What was wrong with your "I have tried in the following way" approach?  That's how I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to map the array with forEach or using the filter to not repeat yourself as you want.

I put a list  to show item by item `<ul> <li>`

- content 1
- content 2
- content 3

```js
listData.map((data) => (
    <div key={data._id)}>
       {data.bucket.code === 'videos' && (
          <ul>
            {data.contents.forEach((content) => {
              <li key={content.somethingToKey}>{content}</li>
            })}
          </ul>
       )}
       {data.bucket.code === 'photos' && ({/* Map only photos contents object */})}          
    </div>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the way you tried it:

```
const renderVideo = (video) => (<div>{video.name}</div>);
const renderPhoto = (photo) => (<div>{photo.name}</div>);

listData.map((data) => (
<div>
{
  data.bucket.code == "videos" ? 
    data.contents.map(video => renderVideo(video)) : 
    data.contents.map(photo => renderPhoto(photo))
}
</div>
));
```